# What sample size do I require when testing for discrete binary variables?

Tags: sampling, sample-size, binary-data, discrete-data

I'd like to preface this question by stating that I am a novice. I may use some terminology incorrectly and would appreciate correction if I do so.

Currently I am running reliability tests to validate the reliability of product prior to shipment. Units are tested for an predetermined amount of time whilst being put under a certain amount of stress/load. Let's say that units are tested for 1 week, whilst being put under peak load at 80% humidity and 50 degrees c.

Now, we have always used a sample size of 30. I don't know where this number comes from. Is it appropriate to use a sample size of 30 when the population is typically in the millions? I assumed that 30 samples would be okay as it would be sufficient to approximate the normal distribution and the CLT would hold (assuming adequate power and significance). However, the results of this testing pass/fail (discrete variables) not continuous data.

How should I determine the correct sample size for discrete binary variables?

Thanks in advance for your guidance and help.